# Regex for truncating file name

Tags: regex

I'm having some trouble putting together a regex for trimming a file name after a certain length. This is being used to rename a large number of files simultaneously, far too many to reasonably rename by hand. Unfortunately, some of our employees like to leave notes on the end of the file name, which is what we're looking to remove.

Example file names, all of these are present and are making matching problematic.

> - ABC - A11B11 - Note.txt
> - ABC - A22B22 (Note).txt
> - ABC - A33B33 | Note.txt

All files will be identical in length, 16 characters specifically. The 1st section will be purely letters, specifically client account names. The 2nd section is a combination of numbers and letters, case ID numbers. The makeup of the 2nd sequence varies with each file name, but are always 6 digits long, and are always a mixture of 2 letters and 4 numbers.

I've tried using regex to pinpoint the number/letter pattern in the 2nd sequence and delete everything afterwards. I've also tried leveraging the 16 character length to delete all characters beyond 16. Unfortunately, I'm not particularly good with regex and I'm not making much headway. Most of my attempts are recognized as a valid regex search, but give incorrect match results.

Any assistance I can get on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given the input `ABC - A1B1 - Note.txt`, what is the output you expect?

Comment: Ideally, it should look like ABC - A1B1.txt. Everything after the 2nd section would need to be removed, including any trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest regex replacement I can conjure up would be:

```
Find:    ^([A-Z0-9]+ - [A-Z0-9]+).*(\.\w+)$
Replace: $1$2
```

### Demo

This approach is to match and capture the first two portions of the file name which you want to retain.  It also captures the file extension.  Then, in the replacement, we form the new file name, effectively removing any notes which might have followed the second section of the name.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did check the demo and it seems to be working ok there, however when I drop that regex into the renaming tool I'm using, it wipes out the entire file name and returns a blank filename. I'm using the PowerRename utility that comes with Microsoft's PowerToys package. I can provide a screenshot if that's helpful.

Comment: It won't help, as I am not familiar with your tool.  Try replacing with `\1\2` or also maybe `\\1\\2`, and see if that would work.

Comment: @offspring991 Maybe this would help with the variable usage:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename#matching-and-variable-examples

Comment: I did try that @TimBiegeleisen, no luck unfortunately

Comment: You could also try removing the starting and ending anchors, that is, do a find on this pattern: `([A-Z0-9]+ - [A-Z0-9]+).*(\.\w+)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It would be better to add the length for the 2nd sequence: `^([A-Z0-9]+ - [A-Z0-9]{6}).*(\.\w+)$`

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found a working search. It's not as hands free as I was originally hoping for and will require adjusting the query for match text for different account names and do them in batches, but it works.

Find: (^ABC - A11\d{2}).*
Replace: $1

It's probably better this way anyway, making automated changes to such a wide range of business documentation makes me a little nervous. This way we can roll out changes slowly to ensure accuracy and avoid data loss or mislabeling.

Thank you for everyone that pitched in ideas.